# Why is the satellite ricochet off the atmosphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

When returning to the atmosphere, if the angle is too small, why is the satellite ricochet off the atmosphere?

What angle is correct and why is it correct?  What does it have to do with the density and pressure of the atmosphere?  I know that satellites will burn down at a vertical angle.

Comment: have you ever skipped pebbles over the sea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-_GezQvflg ? same force analysis

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/how-does-skipping-off-the-atmosphere-work, https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalAcademy/comments/43gq1y/bouncing_off_the_atmosphere_wrongly_described_in/